# Guessing the type from a reference

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have the following structures, where some of them are defined in a framework and some others are not, as indicated in the comments:

```
struct FixedInterface { // from the framework
   virtual ~FixedInterface() {}
}

struct MyAdditionalInterface { // generic, personal/additional interface
};
```

The following structures in my program can derive from the above two structures and are used/passed to the strongly-typed framework

```
struct MyFirstInterface : MyAdditionalInterface, FixedInterface {
};

struct MySecondInterface : FixedInterface {
};

struct MyThirdInterface : MyAdditionalInterface, FixedInterface {
};

// ...

struct MyNthInterface : FixedInterface {
};
```

Now the framework let me define and "inject" a custom function having the following signature. This function is called by the framework when needed:

```
void MyClass::my_function(const FixedInterface& obj) {
}
```

In the body of the above function I need a way to know if obj is an instance of `MyAdditionalInterface` (that is `MyFirstInterface` or `MyThirdInterface`) so that I can cast the obj to use the `MyAdditionalInterface`.

How could I obtain that information? I am free to modify my structures, as long as I do not change the hierarchy and `MyAdditionalInterface` does not have vtable's (no virtual functions or destructors, the reason is the the framework would not allow me that).

I am free to use `Boost` in case. I have access to C++11.

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to `MyAdditionalInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dynamic_cast` will work;

```
MyAdditionalInterface obj2 = dynamic_cast<MyAdditionalInterface const&>(obj)
```

It will throw an exception is `obj` is not a `MyAdditionalInterface`.

However, the use of `dynamic_cast` indicates you should redesign your hierarchy.

#### One possible solution (1)

It appears you only use `MyAdditionalInterface` on top of a `FixedInterface`?

If so,

```
struct MyAdditionalInterface : FixedInterface { ... }
```

Then, define 2 overloads.

```
void MyClass::my_function(const FixedInterface& obj) {
}
void MyClass::my_function(const MyAdditionalInterface& obj) {
}
```

#### One possible solution (2)

For example, let us define

```
struct MyConvolutedInterface : MyAdditionalInterface, FixedInterface {
    ...
}
```

then redefine the classes as follows

```
struct MyFirstInterface : MyConvolutedInterface  {
};

struct MySecondInterface : FixedInterface {
};

struct MyThirdInterface : MyConvolutedInterface  {
};

// ...

struct MyNthInterface : FixedInterface {
};
```

Then, define 2 overloads

```
void MyClass::my_function(const FixedInterface& obj) {
}
void MyClass::my_function(const MyConvolutedInterface& obj) {
}
```

I'm skeptical as to whether this would be the *best* solution in many cases, however.

Comment: The dynamic_cast is fine, I did not try it at first because for some reasons I thought MyAdditionalInterface (other than FixedInterface) had to have a vtable/type info for dynamic_cast to work well. I must read the std better about dynamic_cast. The overload would be fine, but the framwork is a little more complex than what I described and doesn't pick up overloads (thx anyway)

Comment: @Martin `dynamic_cast`s are a really bad idea and quite expensive. They should generally be avoided. Overloads should work, so if they don't, I would ask another question to that affect.